# Difference between formRemote() and submitToRemote() tags

Tags: grails

I am submitting a modal form. When using `formRemote()`, the data does not get submitted but dismisses the modal. When using `submitToRemote()`, the form gets submitted but data-dismiss does not work.

I want to know what is the difference between these two. Do they have specific usages?

Comment: version of Grails?

Comment: i am using grails 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

You should use neither of them. The 1st thing you see when reading the [ref-doc](http://docs.grails.org/2.5.x/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) is:

> The formRemote tag and other Ajax related tags have been deprecated and will be removed from a future version of Grails. Applications may provide their own Ajax tags and/or Javascript plugins may provide Ajax tags of their own.

Indeed such tags are not present in the 3.+ Grails any more.

You should use the Javascript functions directly to provide the Ajax functionality you desire, like (jQuery):

```
<g:form name="form".../>

var form = $( '#form' );
$.ajax({
  url: form.action,
  data: form.serialize()
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  form.dismiss();
});
```

there tons of info on that out there